# Oracle - optimizing query with v$sql

Tags: oracle

In oracle, working with JDBC from Java, I am trying to optimize a specific query:

```
select sql_fulltext from v$sql where last_active_time > ?
```

(? = Some recent date)

The query run time in 1.8 seconds, even if there are no results.
I am wondering how I can I improve it.

The best thing would be if I had an INDEX on last_active_time, but its a view.

My questions is:
How can I improve the running time of the query?
Are there any possible hints I can send?
Is it possible to create a materialized view on this view, and somehow have that indexed?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No. You don't go putting indexes on internal oracle structures. Why are you worried about 1.8 seconds for an occasional query? You aren't adding this query to your application are you? Or are you building some kind of DBA tool?

Comment: I am writing an elobarate query notification feature and would like it to be near real time. What I do is query all recent updates, inserts and deletions. Its an entire things, and I know I can use logminer but cant for non technical reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`V$SQL` is known to be somewhat slow. It is to a large extent a memory structure that you are querying there. If you are concerned about performance (and impact on the system) you should use `V$SQLSTATS` instead.

Quote [from the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3069.htm#REFRN30396)

> *The column definitions for columns in V$SQLSTATS are identical to those in the V$SQL and V$SQLAREA views. However, the V$SQLSTATS view differs from V$SQL and V$SQLAREA in that **it is faster, more scalable, and has a greater data retention***

(Emphasis mine)

There is however a drawback: `V$SQLSTATS` does not contain all the columns from `V$SQL` but it does contain the `SQL_FULLTEXT` column, so it should be OK for your use-case